# Does pe:sheet support nested headers?

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2, handsontable, primefaces-extensions

I am using the PrimeFaces Extensions Sheet component in different contexts and I need different functionalities. I stumbled upon the requirement of nested headers. I see that the underlying component supports this, but I am not sure how to do it with the pe:sheet component.

I already tried setting up the extender cfg property and also tried updating the hot instance, but it does not seem to work.

```
function sheetExtender(){
this.cfg.colHeaders = true;
this.cfg.rowHeaders = true;
this.cfg.nestedHeaders: [
                    ["", {label:"my label", colspan:3}],
                    ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
                ]
```

And also tried the following:

```
PF('widgetName').ht.updateSettings({
colHeaders: true,
rowHeaders: true,
nestedHeaders: [
["", {label:"my label", colspan:3}],
["A", "B", "C", "D"]
]
})
```

I was hoping that one of these approaches would trigger the underlying HandsonTable component to draw nested headers. If non of these work, what would be a workaround for it?

Comment: Hmmm tweaking the JSON should be possible but I have never tried messing with the headers before.  Are you sure your JSON syntax is correct for what you are trying to do?

Comment: According to their documentation yes. Here is a link for it: [headers](https://handsontable.com/docs/7.1.0/Options.html#nestedHeaders)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nested Headers is a HandsonTable PRO only option.  This means it is not included in the 6.2.2 Community Edition that PrimeFaces Extensions Sheet uses and therefore is not available to be used.

[HandsonTable Pricing Info](https://handsontable.com/pricing)

We cannot upgrade to 7.1.0 because its a Non-Commerical License. 6.2.2 was the last Open Source MIT Licensed version.
[Handsontable drops open source for a non-commercial license](https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/issues/5831)